# TypedSort 'by' in Spring Data as described in reference docs does not compile

Tags: spring, sorting

I am a newbee with Spring data and I try to implement a TypeSort 'by'.
The reference docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.paging-and-sorting) show the following example:

```
TypedSort<Person> person = Sort.sort(Person.class);
TypedSort<Person> sort = person.by(Person::getFirstname).ascending()
  .and(person.by(Person::getLastname).descending());
```

This does not compile on my computer (Type mismatch: cannot convert from Sort to Sort.TypedSort). I am using OpenJDK version 13.
After some trying, the following code (a little bit simplified for testing) seems to work ok:

```
TypedSort<Person> sorter = Sort.sort(Person.class);
Sort sorted = sorter.by(Person::getFirstName).descending();
```

Did I miss something in the documentation or is this a documentation flaw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an error in the reference documentation or something they forgot to implement.

As soon as you call .ascending() or .descending(), it's a Sort and no longer a TypedSort.

I guess TypedSort it was only tested/implemented to be used as a 'fluent' API:

```
Sort sort = Sort.sort(Person.class)
  .by(Person::getAddress)
  .by(Address::getZipCode)
  .ascending()
  .and(...)
```

So the following should work, but it's not like in the documentation:

```
TypedSort<Person> person = Sort.sort(Person.class);
Sort sort = person.by(Person::getFirstname).ascending()
  .and(person.by(Person::getLastname).descending());
repository.findAll(sort)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out. But when I try for example:

    TypedSort<Person> sorter2 = person.by(Person::getFirstName);

I get a compiler error: 

    Type mismatch: cannot convert from Sort.TypedSort<String> to Sort.TypedSort<Person> PersonController.java /mypackage/person line 50 Java Problem

So, basically, I cannot reproduce a valid TypedSort by omitting 'ascending'...

Sorry for misformatting. I am not experienced enough yet with Stackoverflow...

Comment: Update: When I change the code to:    
`TypedSort<String> xxx = person.by(Person::getFirstName);    
for (Person person : repository.findAll(xxx.descending())) {    
 System.out.println(person);    
}`        
Everything works as expected.